# HTML5 Builder - chaging pages and weird characters in combobox

Tags: php, javascript, html, html5builder

I made 2 web server pages with the HTML5 Builder. However, I have this 2 simple questions:

1st:
 I don't know how to call the other page (After user insert correct username and password -> show the other page)

2nd: On my Combobox, there is something Related with the Collation that i can't solve... This is the code to load usernames from the database into the combobox:

```
function ComboBox1BeforeShow($sender, $params)
    {
    $this->ComboBox1->Items->clear;    //doesn't work anyway - 3rd question 
    $this->ds_users->DataSet->first();
    while( ! $this->ds_users->DataSet->EOF )
    {
        $this->ComboBox1->AddItem($this->ds_users->DataSet->Fields["Nome"]);
        $this->ds_users->DataSet->next();
    }
    }
```

And I get "FlÃ¡vio Gameiro" instead of "Flávio Gameiro". I checked MYSQL Database's Collation, and its set to "`utf8 -- UTF-8 Unicode`". Tryed with `Latin1` but still the same. Maybe there is anything that can be made in the code I think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, time to answer my own question:

1st -> `header("Location: u_main.php");`

2nd -> http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RadPHP/XE3/en/UTF-8_Setup -> PHP Setup did the trick

3rd -> It is `$this->ComboBox1->clear;` and not `$this->ComboBox1->Items->clear;`

:)